# how to append a label and a value to a dynamic div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a dynamic div and a label, the value i am getting it from response but i am not sure why it is not getting displayed .
Please let me know the fix.

```
$("#letter_customer_name").append('<div class="letter_elements_floating">Vendor ID : '+party.contact.personName+'</div>');
```

Comment: What you have should work. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Check if your element exists with: `console.log($("#letter_customer_name").length);` If it's `0` your element does not (yet) exist in the DOM (or you're using the wrong selector). If it's `greater than 1` you've assigned the same ID to multiple elements.

Comment: @mpf82: hat selector should return either zero or one, JavaScript will typically stop looking for matching elements - with an `id` selector - upon finding the first match (if any). To find *all* elements an attribute selector, `$('[id=letter_customer_name]')`, could be used instead to find all matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<div class="letter_elements_floating">Vendor ID : '+party.contact.personName+'</div>').appendTo("#letter_customer_name");
```